# How do I compress image when uploading to server?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, compression, image-uploading

I have been trying to look at other examples for compression of images. However, I still don't know where and how do I include the codes for compression into. Could anybody help me with this?

```
public void uploadMultipart() {
            //getting name for the image
            String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);


        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

 //method to get the file path from uri
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
//        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
//        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        cursor.close();


        return path;
    }
```

Comment: WHat type of file is it?  If its a jpg or png, its already compressed.  The only file that wouldn't be is a .bmp, which isn't too likely.

Comment: @GabeSechan It is jpg or png, but I saw many examples though when I was searching on how to compress images

Comment: Both of those are already compressed.  If you recompress a jpg, it will lose quality because jpeg is lossy compression.  If you recompress a png it will give you the exact same file (unless you compress it to jpg, in which case you'll lose quality).  If you're ok with losing quality you may be able to compress pngs a bit more but jpegs are already done.  And generally you don't want to lose quality.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see. The reason why I wanted to compress images because I am trying to display images from database on gridview. I realised that it is slow to load images that have huge file size. I thought the photo wasn't caching until someone told me that Picasso already has the caching functionality, so I found out that the problem is the file size of the photo.

Comment: You don't want to compress them, you want to resize them. That's a different thing. You may be able to quick and dirty fix your problem by increasing you're cache size. But to resize, search here for image resizing and you'll find some answers, it's a common question. If it wasn't 2 am and I'm on my phone instead of my laptop I'd link it to you

Comment: @GabeSechan By resizing, would I be able to get the original image size on the database? Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for compress image in Bitmap

Below code for jpeg images

```
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("imagename.png"));
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); // you can set as 90 for compress ration
   Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Below code for png images:

```
   Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("imagename.png"));
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
   Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Otherwise, Here is code which encode the string and send to server as encoded format image

```
  String encodedString ="";
  try {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);

            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Try to above solution. It will work for me.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this before but I am not sure where do I place this piece of code at?

Comment: After retrieving image path from galley or  internal memory. This path will be in string format. this image compress using above code and send to the compressed image.

Comment: I tried using the above method but still couldn't solve it actually. I think I could have implemented wrongly.